Reverse Proxy with ASP.NET Core MVC
I have a project using ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC. In my project, I want to create a controller Home and an action Index. Users will send a URL, along with an external IP and port (for reverse proxy) to the action.
The content of the filtered website, accessed through the reverse proxy, should then be loaded in the view using an internal link from my project. This means users should be able to see the content of the URL they submitted in the view and Razor page, complete any necessary registrations, and navigate through the pages of that URL, while the URLs are opened within my project.
The users also need to provide the IP and port required to tunnel the filtered site along with the URL. All these sites use the HTTPS protocol, and my project must handle SSL and TLS issues properly.
I have been working on this project for about two months. I have tried using YARP, but it doesn’t tunnel with the external IP and port as needed. I also used Nginx, but it requires adding the external IP and port to the server's network interface, which I want to avoid.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or code samples that could help me.
I have used both YARP and Nginx, but both tools have issues with tunneling using an external IP and port for reverse proxying.
